# how to access the python scikit learning code for Random Forest Classifier, Ada Boost Classifier, Extra Trees Classifier

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, random-forest, adaboost

Is it possible to access the python code for Random Forest Classifier, Ada Boost Classifier, Extra Trees Classifier which are python scikit learning methodes can be activated using below code:-

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier
```

i just need to write a review and need to know how these classification algorithms works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/index.html#git-repo) for instructions on how to get the latest sources from git-hub. It is open source, so there is no issue getting the source. Like this:

```
git clone git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

Specifically check out the `ensemble/forest.py` and `ensemble/weight_boosting.py` files from the [Git repository](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn/ensemble).

Comment: Thanx @engineero, i just went to [git_link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py) there is only the abstract method of RandomForestClassifier. how to find the code that include the back-end logic for other 2 as well.

Comment: All three of them can be found on Github in the two files listed in my answer.